# Any way to remove the hidden attribute when robocopying from the root folder?

Tags: windows, robocopy

When I copy from the system root drive like this:

```
robocopy D: C:\users\localUser\pictures\CPics *.jpg *.jpeg *.png *.gif /e /MT:4 /R:0 /NP /SL /SJ /NFL /NDL /XA:o /B /LOG:"C:\Users\anton\Documents\LocalAdminPics.log"
```

(where D: is a Windows 10 root folder for a hard drive I connected on USB)

for some reason the target folder (in this case the "cPics" folder) is Hidden and Read Only.

I tried adding the `/-A:sh` switch to no avail
I also tried adding instead this switch: `/XA:sh` to no avail

I wonder why that folder is copied as Hidden and Read-only and how to prevent this.

Any advice much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this has been an issue with Robocopy for a while now. Even if the folder already exists the hidden attribute will get set again. Also so far I never had it set to read-only do you mean the system attribute?

I usually remove the hidden attribute manually (including the system attribute which has to be removed as well): [`attrib -h -s C:\targetfolder`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/attrib) If you want to remove the read-only add `-r` as well.

Comment: Super thanks for your answer and solution!

Comment: @Antonio23249 You're welcome, if it helped to solve your problem please consider accepting it as an answer or upvoting it.

Comment: Of course, thanks for reminding.